# Unable to load configuration from pip [python/flask/uwsgi]

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

I'm new to Python and I'm having an issue with this small flask app that I'm serving over UWSGI:

After creating the virtualenv and installing all the required dependencies and DB migrations, the app (rest API) appears to be working ok (I'm getting 200 on status endpoints) but one of my dependencies (LlamaIndex) requires a pip install as a part of its process but I'm getting the next error message:

`Command '['/var/www/app/voyager-chatbot/voyager-chatbotenv/bin/uwsgi', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', '/var/www/app/voyager-chatbot/voyager-chatbotenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/readers/llamahub_modules/web/simple_web/requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

The server also logs this error

```
unable to load configuration from pip
```

This does not happen when I run the app on flask in my dev environment, this only happens on the remote server when using UWGSI

this is how my .ini file looks

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = voyager-chatbot.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

I've also tried defining the virtualenv var with the path to the env folder but with no luck

This is my .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve voyager-chatbot
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app/voyager-chatbot
Environment="PATH=/var/www/app/voyager-chatbot/voyager-chatbotenv/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/app/voyager-chatbot/voyager-chatbotenv/bin/uwsgi --ini voyager-chatbot.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For now I solved this by manually installing the dependency but I get that this is not how it should work

```
pip install -r /var/www/app/voyager-chatbot/voyager-chatbotenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/readers/llamahub_modules/web/simple_web/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong becuse I guess is that where it should say `python` it says `uwsgi` because `python -m pip` is syntax for Python command, not uWSGI web server.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change that because that comes from a dependency, I updated the question with my .service config file which comes from the [DigitalOcean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: It's a very bad idea to install Python packages while serving a request of a web client for security reasons. Don't do it please, uWSGI and all other similar frameworks are not designed to do those things.

Comment: How do I control what the dependencies do? (not a lot of experience with python)